# If the mirror image of $P(a,6,9)$ with respect to line $\frac{x-3}{7} =\frac{y-2}{5}=\frac{z-1}{-9}$..

Tags: 3d

> If the mirror image of $P(a,6,9)$ with respect to line $\frac{x-3}{7} =\frac{y-2}{5}=\frac{z-1}{-9}$ is $(20,b,-a-9)$, then find $|a+b|$

The general point of the line is $(3+7k,2+5k,1-9k)$

The direction ratio line joining this point to P is
$$(3+7k-a,5k-4, -8-9k)$$

So the dot product of the two direction ratios must be zero

So
$$k=\frac{7a-73}{155}$$

Now using the fact that
$$3+7k=\frac{20+a}{2}$$

Gives $a=\frac{-3192}{57}$

Beyond which all the values turn into a random mess. Now I don’t know whether I am making computation error or not (even though I tried it many times), or whether my concept is wrong. But I am not getting the answer with this. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some $k$, $(3 + 7k, 2 + 5k, 1-9k)$ is the mid-point of $(a,6,9)$ and $(20, b, -a-9$), hence we have:

\begin{cases}
\dfrac {20+a}2 &= 3+7k\\
\dfrac {b+6}2 &= 2 + 5k\\
\dfrac  {9-a-9}2 &= 1-9k
\end{cases}

Solving the system above gives $a=-56, b=-32, k = -3$.

Comment: Ok, but should the direction ratio method work too?

Comment: Oops, I assumed your formula for $k$ to be incorrect. But it seems that your working out is wrong, since by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k+%3D+%287a-73%29%2F155%2C+3+%2B+7k+%3D+%2820%2Ba%29%2F2) you should obtain the same solution as mine for $a,k$.

Comment: Well, it was quite tedious to solve, but your method is much better. And now that I think about it, yours was probably how it was meant to be done